# Input text field from JSP in java servlet returns null value

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a problem with a text value supposed to receive a date value from the user, so that i can get it from my Manager class . This input returns null.

Here is the code of my text input :

```
<input type='text' name='the_date' id='the_date' value='<%=redac.getDelais()%>'>
```

Here is the code in my servlet class where i get the date from JSP :

```
String date = request.getParameter("the_date");
System.out.print("date"+date);
```

Can anybody help me with this please.

Comment: Is the text field definitely populated with a Date? Is it enabled? If so then post full Servlet code.

Comment: Post the redac.getDelais() function code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this below code is not in form tag
Please check

```
<input type='text' name='the_date' id='the_date' value='<%=redac.getDelais()%>' >
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use JSP tags to output an expression, it prints out something equivalent to String.valueOf(). This means that printing out an object set to null just outputs the string "null". You'll want to do a null-safety check, something like:

`<input type='text' name='the_date' id='the_date' value='<%= redac.getDelais() != null ? redac.getDelais() : "" %>' />`

If the input field is empty, the `request.getParameter()` call will only return null, so you need to check for that in your code, as well, instead of just calling `toString()` on what might be a null reference.

Comment: Hello lea ! In fact, the input field is supposed to be edited by the user , and yeah i should manage the nullpointerexception case. Thanks !